# DWR polling interval

Tags: polling, dwr

Does anyone know how to change the DWR polling interval? This is really hard to find on the net for some reason.

Comment: I have seen it in some mailing list. But i forgot it. I am also in need of knowing that. Hardly i can remember the syntax, this may be give some clue `RemoteClass.method(callback:{}, pollInterval:{});`. If you found correct way, please post it here!!. Thanks

Comment: actually i found that in my code there was a setTimeout loop that was calling the dwr remote functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there isnt a polling interval. you have to poll manually from a script